# How to return a Boolean value from a Function?

Tags: excel, vba, function, boolean, parameter-passing

Trying to write some error checking code. Until now all my code has been one giant sub procedure.

I select cell A1 in my worksheet, which has Test1 inside of the cell. Then I run the MainProgramCode macro.

The results I get:
False Before Function call
You selected data from column 1
False After Function call

I have `OkToProceed = True` right after the `MsgBox "You selected data from column 1"`. But my OkToProceed variable in MainProgramCode is still False after the function?

```
Function Check_User_Select_Range_Column(OkToProceed As Boolean)
If Selection.Column = 1 Then
    MsgBox "You selected data from column 1"
    OkToProceed = True
Else
    MsgBox "You did not select data from column 1, please try again."
    OkToProceed = False
End If
End Function


Sub MainProgramCode()
Dim OkToProceed As Boolean

'Do some error checking
MsgBox OkToProceed & " Before Function call "
OkToProceed = Check_User_Select_Range_Column(OkToProceed)
MsgBox OkToProceed & " After Function call "

'Proceed with MainProgramCode if user data selection is correct
If OkToProceed = True Then
    MsgBox "MainProgramCode"
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: please start using "Option Explicit". it will force you to declare your variables and catch situations like this.  to cure your problem used "Check_User_Select_Range_Column=True" in the first function.

Answer (score 1):

since Check_User_Select_Range_Column does not return anything,
you should change

```
OkToProceed = Check_User_Select_Range_Column(OkToProceed)
```

to

```
Check_User_Select_Range_Column OkToProceed
```

However the following is better.

```
Function Check_User_Select_Range_Column()
If Selection.Column = 1 Then
MsgBox "You selected data from column 1"
Check_User_Select_Range_Column = True
Else
MsgBox "You did not select data from column 1, please try again."
Check_User_Select_Range_Column = False
End If
End Function


Sub MainProgramCode()
Dim OkToProceed As Boolean

'Do some error checking
MsgBox OkToProceed & " Before Function call "
OkToProceed = Check_User_Select_Range_Column()
MsgBox OkToProceed & " After Function call "

'Proceed with MainProgramCode if user data selection is correct
If OkToProceed = True Then
MsgBox "MainProgramCode"
Else
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I submitted an answer to better explain **why** their code didn't work. It's probably best combined into your answer. If you agree, feel free to copy the content of my answer into yours.

Comment: You should define the return data type for the function ` As Boolean` .  Otherwise it will return a Variant

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your issue is that you are not understanding how to return a value from a VBA function. To return a value from a function, you assign that value to the name of the function.

From the [Microsoft Dev Center VBA reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement),

> "To return a value from a function, assign the value to the function
> name. Any number of such assignments can appear anywhere within the
> procedure. If no value is assigned to name, the procedure returns a
> default value: a numeric function returns 0, a string function returns
> a zero-length string (""), and a Variant function returns Empty. "

yamashiro.akihito's answer demonstrates the correct usage.